# Histogram of a pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, histogram, dataframe

I couldn't find anywhere on the site a similar question.

I have a fairly large file, with over 100000 lines and I read it using pandas:

```
df = pd.read_excel("somefile.xls",index_col='Offense Type')
```

ended up with a dataframe consisting of the first column (the index column) and another column, 'Offense_type' and 'Hour' respectively.

'Offense Type' consists of a series of "cathegories" say cat1, cat2, cat3, etc...
'Hour' consists of a series of integer numbers between 1 and 24.

What I would like to do is obtain a histogram of the ocurrences of each number in the dataframe (there aren't that many cathegories It's at most 10 of them)

Here's an ASCII representation of what I want to get"

*(the x's represent the bars in the histogram, they will surely be at a much higher value than 1,2 or 3)*

```
   x        x         # And so on
 x x  x     x x  x    #
 x x  x  x  x x  x    #
 1 2 11 20  5 8 18    #
   Cat1      Cat2     #
```

But i'm getting a single barplot for every line in df using:

```
df.plot(kind='bar')
```

which is basically unreadable:

[image: histogram_of_dataframe]

I've also tried with the hist() and Histogram() function with no luck.

Here's some sample data:

[image: sample_data]

Comment: You'll need to look into pandas [group by](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.2/groupby.html) functionality to get the data into the form you want.

Comment: It's much easier for me to play with the problem if you post some sample data; a few lines from two or three categories, say. Try `df.to_dict{

Comment: ... but not the whole file! also see df.head(n=20), for instance.

Comment: @cphlewis haha of course not the whole file, let me update the body of the question.

Comment: I should have said, paste in a string that I can directly read into a sample dataframe. to_dict writes one out.

Comment: @cphlewis  All the data comes from a `.xls` file. I don't know how to create a string that is able to represent such format.

Comment: Look at my first comment -- it's the DataFrame variable, `df`, that knows how to write out a string that can be re-read from a webpage. Will be useful for future posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long night, I got the answer since every event was ocurring only once I added an extra column in the file with the number one and then indexed the dataframe by this:

```
df = pd.read_excel("somefile.xls",index_col='Numberone')
```

And then simply tried this:

```
df.hist(by=df['Offense Type'])
```

finally getting exactly what I wanted